# Page header of LaTeX and Friends

Tags: header-footer

In [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends) Marc van Dongen shows his book LaTeX and Friends, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46348/15360.

He uses a specific page header as can be seen in the pictures he shows us.

```
Page number <vertical rule> Chapter number
```

or

```
Chapter name <vertical rule> Page number
```

I really like it and would like to get the same format or very similar to it if possible and was wondering how this can be achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option using [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and the offsets provided by the package. Using

```
\fancyhfoffset[OR,EL]{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
```

the headers are offset by an amount equal to `\marginparsep+\marginparwidth` to the right on odd-numbered pages and to the left on even-numbered ones. Then the actual headers are placed using

```
\fancyhead[OR]{\textsc{\leftmark}\quad\smash{\rule[-.2ex]{1pt}{4cm}}\quad\thepage}
\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage\quad\smash{\rule[-.2ex]{1pt}{4cm}}\quad\textsc{\chaptername~\thechapter}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

A complete example code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhfoffset[OR,EL]{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
\fancyhead[OR]{\textsc{\leftmark}\quad\smash{\rule[-.2ex]{1pt}{4cm}}\quad\thepage}
\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage\quad\smash{\rule[-.2ex]{1pt}{4cm}}\quad\textsc{\chaptername~\thechapter}}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `\enspace\enspace` you could use `\quad`. By the way, I don't know where I read it (and how “important” it is) but `\enskip` is the LaTeX preferred way, instead of `\enspace`.

Comment: @Manuel I changed to `\quad`. In this case, there's no difference between `\enspace` and `\enskip`; both are kernel commands: the former is a `\kern`: `\def\enspace{\kern.5em }` the other is a `\hskip`: `\def\enskip{\hskip.5em\relax}`.

Comment: Using `\enspace` may be dangerous if it happens to fall at where a paragraph should start, because it would issue a *vertical* space; `\enskip` would start horizontal mode, instead, but allowing a line break. A header is normally typeset in restricted horizontal mode, so there's no difference between the two, in that case.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to rebuild this with pure komascript and came to this solution:

```
\documentclass[DIV=10,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage{cabin}
\pagestyle{headings}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\sffamily\scshape}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\sffamily}

%setting lengths
\newlength{\ruleWidth}
\setlength{\ruleWidth}{2pt}
\newlength{\pageNumperSpace}
\setlength{\pageNumperSpace}{35pt}
\newlength{\pageNumberHeaderSkip}
\setlength{\pageNumberHeaderSkip}{-\paperwidth+\textwidth+\hoffset+1in+\oddsidemargin}
\newlength{\chapterHeaderSkip}
\setlength{\chapterHeaderSkip}{\pageNumberHeaderSkip+1em+\pageNumperSpace+\ruleWidth}

% scrlayer definitions
\rohead{\smash{\textcolor{black}{\rule[-4pt]{\ruleWidth}{\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+1in}}}\makebox[\pageNumperSpace][c]{\oldstylenums\pagemark}\hspace{\pageNumberHeaderSkip}}
\lehead{\hspace{\pageNumberHeaderSkip}\makebox[\pageNumperSpace][c]{\oldstylenums\pagemark}\smash{\textcolor{black}{\rule[-4pt]{\ruleWidth}{\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+1in}}}}
\cohead{\raggedleft{\headmark} \hspace{\chapterHeaderSkip}}
\cehead{\hspace{\chapterHeaderSkip} \raggedright{\headmark} }

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

[image]