# Page header as in LaTeX and Friends using memoir class

Tags: header-footer, memoir

In [Page header of LaTeX and Friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180348/page-header-of-latex-and-friends) the `fancyhdr` package is used to create the page header of the LaTeX and Friends book. How can I do it using `memoir` class and also on first page where chapter begins?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle} 
\setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
\makerunningwidth{mystyle}{\headwidth}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\thepage\quad\smash{\rule[-0.2ex]{1pt}{4cm}}\quad\textsc{\chaptername~\thechapter}}{}{} 

\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\textsc{\leftmark}\quad\smash{\rule[-0.2ex]{1pt}{4cm}}\quad\thepage} 

\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{\@chapapp\ }{.\ }}
\makeatother

\makepagestyle{plain}
\makerunningwidth{plain}{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\textsc{\leftmark}\quad\smash{\rule[-0.2ex]{1pt}{4cm}}\quad\thepage}{}{}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Test Chapter}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{Test Section}
    \lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you say exactly what problem you're having?

Comment: thank you for your comments, but I still don't know how to align vertical line to the edge of body (textmargin)? What I doing wrong in \setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax} Thanks, tommy

Answer (score 2):

The `memoir`class uses pagestyle `chapter` for the first page of the chapter. So you can do

```
...
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{mystyle}

\begin{document}
...
```

I'm not sure why you redefined the `plain` page style to be the same as `mystyle`, but it would be better to replace that with `\aliaspagestyle{plain}{mystyle}` if you still need it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but a (useful) comment.

Comment: @jon  I dunno. Beats some of David's one-liners... ;). It is, after all, a partial answer to the question. It does not address all parts of the question. But, then, multi-part questions are not really Kosher anyway....

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question, but I thought the OP's MWE showed "how to do it in memoir" already, except for the first page of each chapter.